# Mariadb - interpretation of where clause depedns on conditions order

Tags: mysql, sql-server, mariadb, mariasql

we just migrated from MySQL 5.5.20 to MariaDB 5.5.50
I foud a very strange problem with one query.

This query works on Mysql, but not on MariaDB:

```
SELECT 'za_faktura' AS tabulka,
       za_faktura.id,
       za_faktura.r_cislo,
       za_faktura.o_za_platba,
       za_faktura.a_vystaveni,
       za_faktura.a_splatnost,
       za_faktura.a_zaplaceno,
       0            AS storno,
       za_faktura.p_fakturovano,
       za_faktura.p_fakturovano_mena,
       za_faktura.p_fakturovano_dph,
       za_faktura.p_fakturovano_dph_mena,
       za_faktura.p_zaplaceno,
       za_faktura.p_zaplaceno_mena,
       za_faktura.p_zaplaceno_dph,
       za_faktura.p_zaplaceno_dph_mena
FROM   za_faktura
       INNER JOIN zamn_zakazky_faktury
               ON zamn_zakazky_faktury.i_za_faktura = za_faktura.id
WHERE  zamn_zakazky_faktury.i_za_zakazka = '27580'
       AND za_faktura.i_od = '6660'
       AND za_faktura.i_pro = '3916'
       AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano >= '600.00'
       AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano_mena = 'CZK'
       AND ( ( za_faktura.id = '26282'
               AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano_mena = 'CZK'
               AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano > '600' )
              OR ( za_faktura.id = '26243'
                   AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano_mena = 'CZK'
                   AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano > '3000' )
              OR ( za_faktura.id <> '26282'
                   AND za_faktura.id <> '26243' ) )
ORDER  BY za_faktura.p_fakturovano - '600.00' ASC
```

EXPLAIN EXTENDED from Maria:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra  
1 SIMPLE zamn_zakazky_faktury range  PRIMARY            PRIMARY 4                         NULL 4 75.00 Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using f...  
1 SIMPLE za_faktura           eq_ref PRIMARY,i_od,i_pro PRIMARY 4 guidepraguecz.zamn_zakazky_faktury.i_za_faktura 1 100.00 Using index condition; Using where
```

If i replaced order of ORs in last clause it works with MariaDB:

```
id select_type table type possible_keys key key_len ref rows filtered Extra  
1 SIMPLE zamn_zakazky_faktury ref PRIMARY                    PRIMARY 4 const                4 100.00 Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort  
1 SIMPLE za_faktura               eq_ref  PRIMARY,i_od,i_pro PRIMARY 4 guidepraguecz.zamn_zakazky_faktury.i_za_faktura 1 100.00 Using index condition; Using where
```

Then...

```
SELECT 'za_faktura' AS tabulka,
       za_faktura.id,
       za_faktura.r_cislo,
       za_faktura.o_za_platba,
       za_faktura.a_vystaveni,
       za_faktura.a_splatnost,
       za_faktura.a_zaplaceno,
       0            AS storno,
       za_faktura.p_fakturovano,
       za_faktura.p_fakturovano_mena,
       za_faktura.p_fakturovano_dph,
       za_faktura.p_fakturovano_dph_mena,
       za_faktura.p_zaplaceno,
       za_faktura.p_zaplaceno_mena,
       za_faktura.p_zaplaceno_dph,
       za_faktura.p_zaplaceno_dph_mena
FROM   za_faktura
       INNER JOIN zamn_zakazky_faktury
               ON zamn_zakazky_faktury.i_za_faktura = za_faktura.id
WHERE  zamn_zakazky_faktury.i_za_zakazka = '27580'
       AND za_faktura.i_od = '6660'
       AND za_faktura.i_pro = '3916'
       AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano >= '600.00'
       AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano_mena = 'CZK'
       AND ( ( za_faktura.id <> '26282'
               AND za_faktura.id <> '26243' )
              OR ( za_faktura.id = '26282'
                   AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano_mena = 'CZK'
                   AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano > '600' )
              OR ( za_faktura.id = '26243'
                   AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano_mena = 'CZK'
                   AND za_faktura.p_fakturovano > '3000' ) )
ORDER  BY za_faktura.p_fakturovano - '600.00' ASC
```

Have enyone find any simmilar strange problem? Is there any solution in configuration, etc... I can't find any on the net. If it's a bug in MariaDB, it shoud bring up a lot of commplications in switching from MySQL.

Thanks,

Comment: It's pretty clear that the two queries are not exactly the same except for the ordering of two or conditions.

Comment: I cannot replicate this - are you sure the databases are the same?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the 'strange problem', but this composite index might speed both of them up so that the problem does not matter:

```
za_faktura: INDEX(i_od, i_pro, p_fakturovano_mena, p_fakturovano)
```

The first 3 columns can be in any order; the last one must be last (due to being a 'range').  [*More discussion*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/building-the-best-index-for-a-given-select/) .

It is often better to avoid expressions in `ORDER BY`:

```
ORDER  BY za_faktura.p_fakturovano - '600.00' ASC  -- change to:
ORDER  BY za_faktura.p_fakturovano ASC
```

Those will give you the same ordering.  The former cannot use an index.  (I cannot say for sure whether the index I gave you will cause it to use the index.)

You rearranged just the `OR`, correct?  Since `OR` *usually* cannot be optimized, I would surprised if there is a difference.

Let's see the indexes on the two machines.

Comment: Thanks, the index speed up the query, but my problem is that the first query returns one row on MySQL only. Result from Maria is empty. The second one with rearranged ORs returns one row on both. Table za_faktura has about 65000 rows.

Comment: Please verify that the datasets and query are the same, then file a bug with mariadb.com .